# Get old value from a loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I want to to check every 3 second if the difference of the numbers is higher than 1000. How can I get the old value, for example: 16598, every time?

```
while true; do 
    testbro=$(wc -l < /home/web/log/access.log)
    echo $testbro
    sleep 3 
done
```

It outputs as wanted:

```
16414
16471
16533
16598
16666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to detect when your file grows >= 1000 lines in a 3 second period, you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

last_size=$(wc -l < /home/web/log/access.log)
while true; do
  sleep 3
  curr_size=$(wc -l < /home/web/log/access.log)
  if ((curr_size - last_size >= 1000)); then
    echo "$curr_size"
  fi
  last_size=$curr_size
done
```

Comment: If I had:
16414
16471
16533
16598
16666

The 16666 one being the most updated one, I want also to get 16598 to compare both if they have more than 1000 difference everytime it loops

Comment: I was not updating `last_size`.  Corrected the answer.

Comment: I will break the rules just for you; Thanks <3 !

Comment: Made another correction, it is ideal to sleep as the first thing in the loop so that it takes care of the very first iteration appropriately.